MPAndroidChart Scatter Chart data getting clipped
I have been exploring MPAndroidChart and came across this issue where the data point seem to be clipped off.
Any ways to go about this without changing the axis minmax?
Current Situation
Tried various clip and offset methods of the chart. I'm not sure how to proceed deeper into the stuff.
val binding = TmpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val c = binding.chart.apply {
            setScaleEnabled(false)
            isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
            description.isEnabled = false
            legend.isEnabled = false
            axisRight.isEnabled = false

            xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
            xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
            axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
            axisLeft.axisMaximum = 10f

            axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
            axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
            axisLeft.axisMaximum = 100f
            axisLeft.setLabelCount(5, true)

            clipChildren = false
            clipToOutline = false
            clipToPadding = false
            setClipValuesToContent(false)
            setPadding(100)

            rootView.clipToOutline = false

            xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)
            xAxis.yOffset = 100f
        }

The 2 data points are 0,0 and 5,100.
Expecting points at the edge to still display, preferably hide when it is fully out of the graph.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
